# MultiPartFile deleted too early

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I'm using MultPartFile to upload a .zip from my front-end, **sometimes** this file is deleted before i do anything with it.
I debbug the CommonsMultipartFile.class (intellij) to clean my ideas but i can't find nothing that explain why sometimes i can manipulate the MultPartFile and sometimes no.

In CommonsMultipartFile.class The File is deleted when he pass on isAvailable() method, and when isAvailable() try to validate if he exist, return false.

This is my code

```
 private void limparDiretorioCargasVXESalvarCarga(MultipartFile arquivoMultipartFile, String caminhoDiretorio, String nomeArquivo) throws Step1Exception {
    try {
        File diretorio = new File(caminhoDiretorio);

        if (!diretorio.exists()) {
            diretorio.mkdirs();
        } else {
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(diretorio);
        }
        System.out.println("Diretorio: " + diretorio.getPath());
        File file = new File(diretorio.getPath(), nomeArquivo);

        InputStream InputStreamArquivoFile = arquivoMultipartFile.getInputStream();
        File arquivoFileTemp = new File("/var/lib/mysql-files/cargasvx/baixados/"+arquivoMultipartFile.getOriginalFilename());

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(arquivoFileTemp);
        IOUtils.copy(InputStreamArquivoFile, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();

        this.copiarArquivo(arquivoFileTemp,file);

    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When pass in:

```
        InputStream InputStreamArquivoFile = arquivoMultipartFile.getInputStream();
```

The exeption is throwable.

This is the stack:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: File has been moved - cannot be read again
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.getInputStream(CommonsMultipartFile.java:146)
at br.com.sgsistemas.integrador.services.integracao.ImportacaoService.limparDiretorioCargasVXESalvarCarga(ImportacaoService.java:284)
at br.com.sgsistemas.integrador.services.integracao.ImportacaoService.iniciarImportacaoArquivos(ImportacaoService.java:155)
at br.com.sgsistemas.integrador.services.integracao.ImportacaoService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$422ad70a.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684)
at br.com.sgsistemas.integrador.services.integracao.ImportacaoService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$540126c6.iniciarImportacaoArquivos(<generated>)
at br.com.sgsistemas.integrador.controllers.ImportacaoAPI.lambda$iniciarImportacaoCarga$0(ImportacaoAPI.java:52)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I know that i can `setMaxInMemorySize()`, but that is not the solution that i search. I need to save the File in some temp directory and after I manipulate it, delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what's going wrong in your code, but MultipartFile has a `transferTo` method that you can use to replace much of your code. By reducing the amount of code that you write, you will minimize the chance of a bug, and may perhaps see your issue go away...

Comment: Hi Grey, thank's for your anwser, but i did all this code because the `transferTo()` didn't work. It throw the same error that the `getInputStream()`.

Comment: Yes, so now, you've proven that transferTo() was not the problem, and you can put that back, and remove the extra code that you wrote. The actual problem is fairly obviously elsewhere.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did u ever resolve this? My issue is that I'm using the MultipartFile in a loop and after the first iteration it appears that the file is deleted. This only happens on my server, not on my own machine

Comment: @AdamJohnston Did you ever solve this issue? I'm also having same problems. The error happens only on AWS Corretto. On my machine the upload works without issues. I read somewhere that it could be because of `@Async` but I'm not using that. I don't touch the `MultipartFile` elsewhere, and the first time that I try to do anything with it on the server it throws `FileNotFoundException`. It's driving me nuts.